# Error encountered while using Hibernate to save data processed in Servlets

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

Hi guys am practising hibernate and servlets by building a simple web application form. The program works fine if I don't use hibernate to save data and just use JSP and servlets. Now if I add my Hibernate code its producing this error.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.ApplicationForm.ApplicationForm] in context with path [/ApplicationForm] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at com.ApplicationForm.AppFormServletHelper.doPost(AppFormServletHelper.java:54)
        at com.ApplicationForm.ApplicationForm.doPost(ApplicationForm.java:24)
//More errors messages here
```

The error message always points to this class which contains my Hibernate instance
class AppFormServletHelper. (Full Code below)

```
public class AppFormServletHelper extends ApplicationFormServletBase {
 
    private static AppDetails applicant = new AppDetails();
    private static SaveApplicantData list = new SaveApplicantData();

    
    public AppFormServletHelper(HttpServlet servlet, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        super(servlet, request, response);
        
    }
    
    public void doPost() throws ServletException, IOException{
        int userID=0;
        String stringUserID, firstName, lastName, address, mobile, landLine;
        String sex, university;
        
        
        stringUserID = request.getParameter((Integer.toString(userID)));
        firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        address = request.getParameter("address");
        mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");
        landLine = request.getParameter("landLine");
        sex = request.getParameter("sex");
        university = request.getParameter("university");
        //more request.getParameter lines here
        
        recordApplicantDetails(userID, firstName, lastName, address, mobile, landLine, sex);
        recordApplicantEducation(university, uniDateGrad, hsGrad, hsDateGrad, elem, elemDateGrad);
        recordApplicantEmployment(companyN, jobRole, jobResp);
        
        //Save data using hibernate
**##Error pointing to this line**
        **HibernateSaveData save = new HibernateSaveData();
        save.beginHibernateTransaction(applicant);**
                
        list.addApplicantData(applicant);
        list.setApplicantData(applicant, list);
        
        request.setAttribute("AppDetails", applicant);
    
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/UserDetails.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
        
    }
//Implementation of recordApplicantDetails method
//Implementation of recordApplicantEducation method
//Implementation of recordApplicantEmployment method

}
```

This is ApplicationFormServletBase class

```
@WebServlet("/appFormServlet")
public class ApplicationForm extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        AppFormServletHelper controllerHelper = new AppFormServletHelper(this,req, resp);
        controllerHelper.doPost();
    }
```

This is my HibernateSaveData class

```
public class HibernateSaveData {
    
    private Session session; 
    
    public void beginHibernateTransaction(AppDetails details){
        session = new HibernateFactoryUtil().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(details);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
        }
        catch (HibernateException e){
            if (session.getTransaction()!=null){
                session.getTransaction().rollback();    
            }
            System.out.println("Hibernate exception occured: "+ e);
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Also I already configured my hibernate.cfg.xml and I am using @WebServlet annotation for servlet so I didn't configure any xml mapping. I did not post all of the codes but I'll put them up if it helps in solving this problem. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

This is how I set my folders
[image]

and this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ApplicationForm</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.ApplicationForm.StoreData.AppDetails"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Build your project and try to re-compile your classes and check if
>   error still exists

Comment: Hi Murali, I already checked and build my java files many times and problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that Hibernate (and in this case HibernateException) isn't in your classpath when you deploy.
Since I'm assuming your using an IDE (such as Eclipse) and in the IDE you don't get any compilation errors, the fault is most likely in your build/deploy process.

You'll have to tell us how your build/deploy (are you using maven? are you packaging a war through eclipse and uploading it to a server? where does the Hibernate library located, and does the classpath know about it? etc...) in order to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: hi illniyar thanks for helping out. I edited my post and included how I set my folders and packages and also included my hibernate configuration file. I didn't use maven, I just included jar files using the add jars in the build path option of Eclipse. I added hibernate3.jar and use mysql for storing data. Hope that helps

Comment: Also the way my project structure was setup, its automatically done by eclipse by using the Dynamic Web Project option.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the file hibernate3.jar in WEB-INF/lib folder.